# Every word from babab to zyzyz

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, combinatorics

Your task is to write a program that will output a readable list of every five letter words with the structure:

**consonant - vowel - consonant - vowel - consonant**

The output should be sorted alphabetically with one word per line and no words repeated twice. It can be lowercase or uppercase but not mixed. So the list could start and end like this:

```
babab  
babac  
babad  
...  
zyzyw  
zyzyx  
zyzyz
```

Vowels are **a**-**e**-**i**-**o**-**u**-**y**, the other 20 English-alphabet letters are consonants.
Words don't have to be actual dictionary words.
Shortest code wins.

*Note: A few years ago I stumbled upon a program on a university website that did exactly that. Turns out my first and last name fit the c-v-c-v-c constraint, and i'd been googling myself.*

Comment: I see two things here. First, there are a ridiculous amount of words like this. How do you expect to test the entries? Also, there are many names that fit that constraint. The first that comes to mind is *Jacob*, although others like *Lucas* also fit

Comment: @TrojanByAccident I believe the challenge requires all possible matching letter combinations, regardless of whether they are names/English words. "Words don't have to be actual dictionary words."

Comment: @trichoplax if you mean my second point, I was referring to the OP's Note at the bottom

Comment: @TrojanByAccident My apologies - I didn't realise they were separate points. In that case, I guess a program to test the outputs would be helpful. I make it 20*6*20*6*20=288,000 words in total, around 1,728,000 characters including delimiters. I'm not sure if a Stack Snippet can handle strings that long.

Comment: @TrojanByAccident The note was just to point out how I had the idea for the question, not an extra challenge. Also, my first name is Kevin :)

Comment: Does the order in which the names are output, matter? If so, can you please explain that order in more detail?

Comment: @smls By incremental I mean that after _babaz_ comes _babeb_, not _babob_ or _babib_. So we work our way through vowels and consonants in the order they come in the alphabet.

Comment: Can we use uppercase instead of lowercase?

Comment: Can we return a list of strings instead?

Comment: @Adám The output should be formatted like in the example, lowercase, each word to its line, no repeats.

Comment: @wilks [Relevant meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/8478) -- Strict i/o formats aren't appreciated in this SE community. This challenge is focusing on generating c-v-c-v-c words, not inserting newlines between words, no?

Comment: @JungHwanMin Thanks for the link, first time here and I didn't know about this. I saw it as a readable and alphabetical list of all the c-v-c-v-c words. So I agree that upper or lowercase really doesn't matter, but I also think that one very long string or, say some nested arrays, whilst technically valid wouldn't be a great answer.

Comment: Having run a few of the upvoted answers to this question, they obviously do not comply with "The output should be incremental with each word on its own line". Has this requirement been relaxed and if so can you edit the question to reflect this? I reckon I could lose quite a few bytes if my answer wasn't restricted by the format.

Answer (score 29):

### Mathematica, <s>72</s> <s>65</s> 61 bytes

```
Print@@@Tuples@{a=##/(b=#5#9#15#21#25#)&@@Alphabet[],b,a,b,a}
```

For testing, I recommend replacing `Print@@@` with `""<>#&/@`. Mathematica will then display a truncated form showing the first few and last few words, instead of taking forever to print 288,000 lines.

#### Explanation

I finally found a use for dividing strings. :)

I've been intrigued by the possibility of adding or multiplying strings for a while, but the actual use cases are fairly limited. The main point is that something like `"foo"+"bar"` or `"foo"*"bar"` (and consequently, the short form `"foo""bar"`) is completely valid in Mathematica. However, it doesn't really know what to do with the strings in arithmetic expressions, so these things remain unevaluated. Mathematica *does* apply generally applicable simplifications though. In particular, the strings will be sorted into canonical order (which is fairly messed up in Mathematica, once you start sorting strings containing letters of various cases, digits and non-letters), which is often a dealbreaker, but doesn't matter here. Furthermore, `"abc""abc"` will be simplified to `"abc"^2` (which is a problem when you have repeated strings, but we don't have that either), and something like `"abc"/"abc"` will actually cancel (which we'll be even making use of).

So what are we trying to golf here. We need a list of vowels and a list of consonants, so we can feed them to `Tuples` to generate all possible combinations. My first approach was the naive solution:

```
Characters@{a="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz",b="aeiouy",a,b,a}
```

That hardcoded list of consonants does hurt a bit. Mathematica does have an `Alphabet` built-in which would allow me to avoid it, if I were able to remove the vowels in a cheap way. This is where it gets tricky though. The simplest way to remove elements is `Complement`, but that ends up being longer, using one of the following options:

```
{a=Complement[Alphabet[],b=Characters@"aeiouy"],b,a,b,a}
{a=Complement[x=Alphabet[],b=x[[{1,5,9,15,21,25}]]],b,a,b,a}
```

(Note that we don't need to apply `Characters` to the whole thing any more, because `Alphabet[]` gives a list of letters, not a string.)

So let's try that arithmetic business. If we represent the entire alphabet as a product of letters instead of a list, then we can remove letters by simple division, due to the cancelling rule. That saves a lot of bytes because we won't need `Complement`. Furthermore, `"a""e""i""o""u""y"` is actually a byte shorter than `Characters@"aeiouy"`. So we do this with:

```
a=##/(b="a""e""i""o""u""y")&@@Alphabet[]
```

Where we're storing the consonant and vowel products in `a` and `b`, respectively. This works by writing a function which multiplies all its arguments with `##` and divides them by the product of vowels. This function is *applied* to the alphabet list, which passes each letter in as a separate argument.

So far so good, but now we have

```
{a=##/(b="a""e""i""o""u""y")&@@Alphabet[],b,a,b,a}
```

as the argument to `Tuples`, and those things are still products, not lists. Normally, the shortest way to fix that is putting a `List@@@` at the front, which turns the products into lists again. Unfortunately, adding those 7 bytes makes it longer than the naive approach.

However, it turns out that `Tuples` doesn't care about the heads of the inner lists at all. If you do

```
Tuples[{f[1, 2], f[3, 4]}]
```

(Yes, for an undefined `f`.) You'll get:

```
{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}
```

Just as if you had used a `List` instead of `f`. So we can actually pass those products straight to `Tuples` and still get the right result. This saves 5 bytes over the naive approach using two hardcoded strings.

Now the `"a""e""i""o""u""y"` is still fairly annoying. But wait, we can save a few bytes here as well! The arguments of our function are the individual letters. So if we just pick out the right arguments, we can reuse those instead of the string literals, which is shorter for three of them. We want arguments `#` (short for `#1`), `#5`, `#9`, `#15`, `#21` and `#25`. If we put `#` at the end, then we also don't need to add any `*` to multiply them together, because (regex) `#\d+` is a complete token that can't have any non-digit appended to it. Hence we end up with `#5#9#15#21#25#`, saving another 4 bytes.

Comment: Reads explanation. So... basically magic.

Comment: I'm surprised and impressed by your `Tuples` trick. That's entirely undocumented, right? And unexpected given how the two-input form `Tuples[list,n]` deals with `list` not having the `List` head (to me at least)!

Comment: @ASimmons [The object _list_ need not have head `List`. The head at each level in the arrays generated by `Tuples` will be the same as the head of _list_.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html?q=Tuples)

Comment: @ngenisis I find that wording very confusing. Because it's not clear that this refers to the *outer* list when using multiple lists. Indeed `Tuples[f[{1,2}, {3,4}]]` gives `{f[1, 3], f[1, 4], f[2, 3], f[2, 4]}` instead. It's not documented that the inner head is completely ignored.

Comment: @ASimmons cc. ^

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood

Comment: Possibly the one-argument form of `Tuples` was added later than the two-argument form? That would explain the confusing documentation.

Answer (score 14):

## Perl, 47 bytes

```perl
#!perl -l
/((^|[aeiouy])[^aeiouy]){3}/&&print for a..1x5
```

Counting the shebang as one.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@6@voRFXE52YmplfWhmrGR0HY1Ub1@qrqRUUZeaVKKTlFykk6ukZVpj@//9fNwcA)

Comment: This is nice, well done! Any reasons you're not using `say` ?

Comment: Thanks. I [disagree](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7539/4098) that `-M5.01` should be 'free'.

Comment: I like your opinion on `-M5.010`. And the intersting part in the golfing isn't to replace `print` with `say`...

Comment: Isn't `-E` (and subsequently `say`) a freebie?

Comment: @Zaid See Primo's first [comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106567/every-word-from-babab-to-zyzyz/106574#comment259152_106574)

Answer (score 12):

## Python 3 - 110 bytes

```
a,b="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz","aeiouy";print(*(c+d+e+f+g for c in a for d in b for e in a for f in b for g in a))
```

Straightforward looping fun :)

Comment: Think our ideas are the same but you beat me by 10 with Python 3!

Comment: I was just about to post a python2 equivalent using this approach.  Too slow, a vote for you instead.

Answer (score 10):

### Ruby, <s>72 71</s> 52 bytes

```
puts (?z..?z*5).grep /#{["[^aeiouy]"]*3*"[aeiouy]"}/
```

Thanks to Value Ink for the basic idea, which brought that down to 60 bytes.

Comment: It's shorter to generate a list of 5-letter words and using `grep`. If you generate a range that uses lower-case strings, you get a sequence of the lower-case words only. `puts ("babab".."zyzyz").grep /#{["[^aeiouy]"]*3*"[aeiouy]"}/` for 60 bytes

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

**05AB1E** uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
žP3ãžO3ãâ€øJ€¨ê»
```

**Explanation**

```
žP3ã                # push all combinations of 3 consonants
    žO3ã            # push all combinations of 3 vowels
        â           # cartesian product
         €ø         # zip each pair of [ccc,vvv] (c=consonant,v=vowel)
           J        # join to list of strings ['cvcvcv','cvcvcv' ...]
            €¨      # remove last vowel from each
              ê     # sort and remove duplicates
              »     # join on newlines
```

For testing purposes I recommend replacing `žP` with a few consonants and `žO` with a few vowels.

[Example using 5 consonants and 3 vowels](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@UlJySlq5kfHixUmJqJog@vOhR05rDO7yA5KEVh1cd2v3/PwA)

Comment: nice use of Cartesian product. Wouldn't've thought of that.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>120</s> <s>102</s> 94 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
lambda:map(''.join,product(*(('AEIOUY','BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ')*3)[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PcrJCoMwFEDRvV/xECSJSKF0J7iodrSDHexMF2mjkKJ5kqT4@ZZ20eXl3K7UWIO0hbaIlQFZN6it75RRxeuH4GHNG0pI74VSBY1G8X5a6lNKhuN5driQgMTJaDKdpYvlar3Z7vb58XS@EuYP2K0f3hnr2qikzGm0VBbcHC2voEUtDITgCderCkXbvyeoLJfKQDpMsvi7GNej5FcEpIKWdR8)

Answer (score 8):

## Pure Bash, 74

```bash
v={a,e,i,o,u,y}
c={b,c,d,f,g,h,{j..n},{p..t},v,w,x,z}
eval echo $c$v$c$v$c
```

Straightforward brace expansion.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#JcM7DoAgEEDB3lNQUL7sDTgMIorGiIWuH8LZsXCSaeqKJzKTOXlqF1zpCQyMTCTKIrJVyi5yVJSLm7d2Uf1qYkjZ2GD139oH).

---

If each item must be on its own line, then we have:

## Pure Bash, 84

```bash
v={a,e,i,o,u,y}
c={b,c,d,f,g,h,{j..n},{p..t},v,w,x,z}
eval printf '%s\\n' $c$v$c$v$c
```

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <s>88</s> <s>86</s>  <s>84</s> 80 bytes

pretty string increment :)
6 bytes saved by @Christoph

```php
for($s=$v=aeiouy;++$s<zyzza;preg_match("#[^$v]([$v][^$v]){2}#",$s)&&print"$s
");
```

loops through all strings from `bababa` to `zyzyz` and tests if they match the pattern. Run with `-nr`.

Comment: Lol, golfing with a buggy language spec, I like it

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It´s not a bug. It´s a feature. :D I am sad they embedded an implicit cast to integer into `$a="001";$a++;` some day. That was a very unconvenient change.

Comment: I didn't say the "feature" was a bug, I said the specification was a bug. Sort of like how in JavaScript, `typeof null == "object"`

Comment: `for($s=$v=aeiouy;++$s<zyzza;)preg_match("#[^$v][$v][^$v][$v][^$v]#",$s)&&print"$s\n";` saves you 1 char. Sadly you have to change echo to print to use `&&`. Replacing `\n` with a real line break saves another.

Comment: you might save some chars using `"#([^$v][$v]){2}​[^$v]#"` but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @Christoph: Idk why, but `([^$v][$v]​){2}[^$v]` does not work in the loop, while `[^$v]([$v]​[^$v]){2}` does. Both work standalone (even with the variable) though.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
l="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz":"aeiouy":l
mapM(l!!)[0..4]
```

`mapM func list` builds all words by taking the possible characters for index i from the list returned by `func (list!!i)`.

Edit: @xnor found 2 bytes to save and looking at his solution, I found another one.

Comment: `mapM id$take 5$cycle["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz","aeiouy"]` saves a byte.

Comment: Better yet, `mapM(cycle["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz","aeiouy"]!!)[0..4]` or `mapM(["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz","aeiouy"]!!)[0,1,0,1,0]`. It would be nice not to hardcode the vowels and consonants, but `mapM(\n->[x|x<-['a'..'z'],elem x"aeiou"==odd n])[0..4]` doesn't quite make it.

Comment: @xnor: Thanks! Replacing `cycle` from your first variant with explicit recursion saves an additional byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 85 bytes

```python
W='BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ'
for s in['AEIOUY',W]*2:W=[w+c for w in W for c in s]
print W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9xW3cnZxc3dw8vbx9cvIDAoOCQsPCJKnSstv0ihWCEzL1rd0dXTPzRSXSc8VsvIKtw2ulw7WQEkWw6UVQgHM5NBzOJYroKizLwShfD//wE)

I'm back six years later with a golf. The string `W` of consonants can also be used as the result of the first loop which gives all first-letter options. The fact that it's a string rather than a list is harmless because we just need to iterate over it. We can then write the other four letter sets cleanly as `['AEIOUY',W]*2`.

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 92 bytes

```python
f=lambda i=-4,s='':i*[s]or sum([f(i+1,s+c)for c in i%2*'AEIOUY'or'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ'],[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRIdNW10Sn2FZd3SpTK7o4Nr9Iobg0VyM6TSNT21CnWDtZMw0olKyQmaeQqWqkpe7o6ukfGqmeX6Tu5Ozi5u7h5e3j6xcQGBQcEhYeEaUeqxMdq/m/oCgzr0QjTUNT8z8A)

Can't let `itertools` win out. Iterative is 1 byte longer in Python 2.

```python
W='',
for s in(['AEIOUY','BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ']*3)[1:]:W=[w+c for w in W for c in s]
print W
```

Comment: This is awesome ^_^

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 21 bytes

```
11Y2'y'h2Y2X~6Myyy&Z*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29oGGmkXqmeYRRpFFFn5ltZWakWpfX/PwA) (but output is truncated).

```
11Y2   % Push 'aeiou' (predefined literal)
'y'    % Push 'y'
h      % Concatenate: gives 'aeiouy'
2Y2    % Push 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' (predefined literal)
X~     % Set symmetric difference: gives 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
6M     % Push 'aeiouy' again
yyy    % Duplicate the second-top element three times onto the top. The stack now
       % contains 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz', 'aeiouy', 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz',
       % 'aeiouy', 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
&Z*    % Cartesian product of all arrays present in the stack. Implicity display
```

Comment: I think this should work, shaving a byte: `11Y2'y'h2Y2yX~yyy&Z*` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29oGGmkXqmeYRRpVBlRV1lZqRal9f8/AA "MATL – TIO Nexus"))

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Unfortunately, that creates the `vcvcv` pattern, not `cvcvc` as required. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```
f=(s='',i=4)=>{for(c of i%2?'aeiouy':'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz')i?f(s+c,i-1):console.log(s+c)}
```

#### Edits

- ETHproductions: -1 byte by removing extraneous group around ternary operator in `for` statement

#### Explanation

This defines a 5-deep recursive function that uses the parity of its depth of call to determine whether to iterate vowels or consonants. On each iteration, it checks to see whether to recurse or print by checking the amount of recursions left, and concatenates the letter of its current iteration to the end of the 5 character string that is currently being built depth-first.

Alternative 89 byte solution assuming ISO8859-1 encoding:

```
f=(s='',i=4)=>{for(c of i%2?'aeiouy':btoa`mÇ_äiéª»-¿s`)i?f(s+c,i-1):console.log(s+c)}
```

Alternative 96 byte solution that returns entire output as single string:

```
f=(s='',i=4,o='')=>eval("for(c of i%2?'aeiouy':'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz')o+=i?f(s+c,i-1):s+c+`\n`")
```

**Run at your own risk.** For the 91 byte solution, just use `f()` and for the 97 byte alternative, use `console.log(f())`.

Comment: I tried turning the solution into a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) in two different ways. Using the shorthand form supported only by Firefox is the same length: `f=(s='',i=2)=>(for(c of(i%2?'aeiouy':'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'))for(q of i?f(s+c,i-1):[s+c])q)` Using the standard form is unfortunately a byte longer: `function*f(s='',i=2){for(c of(i%2?'aeiouy':'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'))yield*i?f(s+c,i-1):[s+c]}` Still waiting for the day when a generator is the shortest option...

Comment: btw, you can remove the inner parens in the `for...of` statement to save a byte

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
@W:@Dg:2jcb:eac@w\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@@8QbuXgkm5llJWcZJWamOxQHvP/PwA)

#### Explanation

```
@W:@D                 The list ["aeiouy", "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"]
     g:2jcb           The list ["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz", "aeiouy", "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz", "aeiouy", "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"]
           :ea        Take one character of each string
              c       Concatenate into a single string
               @w     Write to STDOUT followed by a newline
                 \    Backtrack: try other characters of the string
```

Comment: I was surprised at the need for the `g` and `b`, but testing it, this is because `j` seems to refuse to take a list of strings as input? `:ea` really shows off the strengths of Prolog/Brachylog, though, and is a step that most other languages find much more difficult.

Comment: @ais523 Yes, I was also suprised that the `g` and `b` were needed. `j` seems to be bugged and this is due once again to the difficulty of distinguishing a list of arguments from just a list. I might fix this though this will once again complexify the implementation. I might as well just not fix it and invest my time on fixing the core problem in a new version of Brachylog.

Answer (score 5):

### C, <s>201</s> <s>199</s> <s>186</s> <s>184</s> <s>183</s> <s>169</s> 163 bytes

Doing it a bit differently than with the previous basic counting method:

```
f(){for(char*c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz",*v="aeiouy",i[5]={0},*s[]={c,v,c,v,c},j=0;j<5;puts("")){for(j=5;j--;putchar(s[j][i[j]]));for(;j++<5&&!s[j][++i[j]];i[j]=0);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
f() {
    for(char *c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz", *v="aeiouy", i[5]={0}, *s[]={c,v,c,v,c}, j=0; j<5; puts("")) {
        for (j=5; j--; putchar(s[j][i[j]])) ;
        for (; j++ < 5 && !s[j][++i[j]]; i[j]=0) ;
    }
}
```

And written in a bit more conventional way:

```
f() {
    char *c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz", *v="aeiouy", i[]={0,0,0,0,0}, *s[]={c,v,c,v,c}, j=0;
    while (j>=0) {
        for (j=0; j<5; j++) putchar(s[j][i[j]]); // output the word
        while (--j>=0 && !s[j][++i[j]]) i[j]=0; // increment the counters
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Basically, *i* are the counters, and *s* the array of strings containing all the chars over which we should iterate, for each counter. The trick is the inner *while* loop: it is used to increment the counters, starting from the rightmost one. If we see that the next character we should display is the ending null char, we restart the counter to zero and the "carry" will be propagated to the next counter.

Thanks Cristoph!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: `char *c` I think the space is unnecessary.

Comment: @Christoph You're right, thanks.

Comment: `f(){char*c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz",*v="aeiouy",i[]={0,0,0,0,0},*s[]={c,v,c,v,c},j=0;while(j>=0){for(j=0;j<5;++j)putchar(s[j][i[j]]);for(;--j>=0&&!s[j][++i[j]];)i[j]=0;puts("");}}` gets you to 177. Come on you can do even better ;).

Comment: Using `i[5]={0}` instead of `i[]={0,0,0,0,0}` saves 7 bytes.

Comment: `char*c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz",*v="aeiouy",i[5]={0},*s[]={c,v,c,v,c};f(int j=0){for(;j<5;)putchar(s[j][i[j++]]);for(;j-->0&&!s[j][++i[j]];)i[j]=0;puts("");j<0||f();}` 164. Note that in general to get those versions compile I need `int f()` not sure if some compilers allow it without.

Comment: @Christoph All right, let's invite recursivity in... I thought that was already pretty twisted, but it seems there are no limits. I'm not sure about the `s[j][i[j++]]`, though. Isn't that undefined, per the C specifications? I thought the order of evaluation (j being used twice and with a postincrement) wasn't guaranteed.

Comment: If that bothers you it only saves 1 char: `f(){for(char*c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz",*v="aeiouy",i[5]={0},*s[]={c,v,c,v,c},j;j>=0;puts("")){for(j=-1;++j<5;)putchar(s[j][i[j]]);for(;j-->0&&!s[j][++i[j]];)i[j]=0;}}` 165 nonrecursive.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks. There is another thing that bothers me: j isn't actually initialized when declared, and you're testing it right away. Did I miss something?

Comment: Your making this quite hard: `f(){for(char*c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz",*v="aeiouy",i[5]={0},*s[]={c,v,c,v,c},j=0;j<5;puts("")){for(j=5;j--;putchar(s[j][i[j]]));for(;j++<5&&!s[j][++i[j]];i[j]=0);}}` 163 nonrecursive without undefined behavior (as far as I can still tell at this point)

Comment: @Christoph Aha, thanks. Good job. But you seemed to enjoy it, that's why I was pushing the challenge (no, I'm kidding: I did that just because I'm a pain in the ass). Seriously, thanks for the enlightenments.

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge, 95 bytes

```
::45*%\45*/:6%\6/:45*%\45*/:6%\6/1g,2g,1g,2g,1g,55+,1+:"}0":**-!#@_
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz
aeiouy
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Ojo0NSolXDQ1Ki86NiVcNi86NDUqJVw0NSovOjYlXDYvMWcsMmcsMWcsMmcsMWcsNTUrLDErOiJ9MCI6KiotISNAXwpiY2RmZ2hqa2xtbnBxcnN0dnd4egphZWlvdXk&input=), although note that the output will be truncated.

This is just a loop over the range 0 to 287999, outputting the index as a mixed based number 20-6-20-6-20, with the "digits" of the number retrieved from the tables on the last two lines.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 70 bytes

```
$_=<a e i o u y>;my \c=[grep .none,"a".."z"];.say for [X~] c,$_,c,$_,c
```

Explanation of the interesting part:

```
.say for [X~] c, $_, c, $_, c

              c, $_, c, $_, c  # list of five lists
         [X ]                  # lazily generate their Cartesian product
           ~                   # and string-concatenate each result
.say for                       # iterate to print each result
```

The code before that just generates the list of vowels (`$_`) and the list of consonants (`c`), which is regrettably verbose.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>120</s> 117 bytes

Thanks to @WheatWizard for the tabs tip.

```python
x,y='aeiouy','bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
for a in x:
 for e in x:
	for b in y:
		for c in y:
			for d in y:print b+a+c+e+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PcdLFkAgFADQMat4swavFTjHYvohn5BQNh/FcWc3ehpqwpSe90Ao4UI2bdcP42SW1W7uOP1Fyma2wEAb8FUJKepLkcJTwpM88S9Xvl2sNg44MhSoUMZ4Aw)

Not sure that this can be golfed much. Try it online truncates at 128KB but shows enough to give an idea. A local run with debug code to count the words gave a total of 288000. Runs in about 45 seconds if anyone wants to test.

```
zyzyv
zyzyw
zyzyx
zyzyz
Total word count: 288000
```

Non-compliant and therefore non-competing version (prints out nested arrays instead of the specified format) for 110 bytes:

```python
x,y='aeiouy','bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
print[[[[c+a+d+b+e for e in y]for d in y]for c in y]for b in x]for a in x]
```

Comment: Was my first implemenation :)

Comment: Instead of using spaces for all your indentation you can use spaces for the single indent and tabs for double.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 82 bytes

```
f=(i=5)=>i?[for(s of f(i-1))for(c of i%2?'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz':'aeiouy')s+c]:['']
```

Returns an array of strings. Very fast version for <s>102</s> 101 (1 byte thanks to @ETHproductions) bytes:

```
_=>[for(i of c='bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz')for(j of v='aeiouy')for(k of c)for(l of v)for(m of c)i+j+k+l+m]
```

Comment: Nice. There's an extraneous space in the fast version which can be removed for 101 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 6, 53 Bytes

```
/<-[aeiouy]>**3%<[aeiouy]>/&&.say for [...] <a z>Xx 5
```

Takes a little time to have any output. Very inefficient.  Does the job.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 71 bytes

```perl
map{push@{1+/[aeiouy]/},$_}a..z;$"=",";say for glob"{@1}{@2}"x2 ."{@1}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#Ky1OVTDVMzA0sP6fm1hQXVBanOFQbaitH52YmplfWhmrX6ujEl@bqKdXZa2iZKuko2RdnFipkJZfpJCek5@kVO1gWFvtYFSrVGGkoAfmKf3/DwA)

**Explanation**

*I'll add more explanations later.*

`map{push@{1+/[aeiouy]/},$_}a..z;` creates two arrays: `@1` contains the consonants, and `@2` contains the vowels.
`glob` when call with arguments like `{a,b}{c,d}` returns all permutations of the elements in the braces.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender and 1 byte thanks to kaine*

```
"aeiouy"_'{,97>^\1$1$1$N]:m*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#fVFLS8QwEL7nVwyrIMhW8CR6EGTxKqIefTDbTE0gTUom3W7xx9dJu3W7F1sKbfq9Zr5hhWRD26@@gM7guWUDyRCw3cMudOQY0GvQbeNsiYnUxc/69uYe5FrCOxMcAbrG4JaS@oT5EtBrX9eUoi2BKYG2VUWRfEkQqpE7s6CzaVKbjNfQW3Kax6MyeA4efWII3vXq/cShwwZSkKcLQI5qEpy6Ps/3AbIJTT8NRiKliyqGupDvItNY0vlvURgRo5CJJG@2JlawtHozliESt06SWD8NECP2sKWsccxZTFMU/52op6X2g9aA4Klz1svEBiOWieKci6SHw8qc5aQ@ltxH@Yl@inIlvUg62lHsk8mpdBBBDlBhzKFn4OlobHMpIh@lT2Twsst9rt0m2RDG9FfYaKLu6ssj@YV0O7EP62g5G2@ERmzFsIlBEImH4Rc) (Note that the output gets cut off on TIO)

**Explanation**

```
"aeiouy"_ e# Push the six vowels and duplicate
'{,97>    e# Push the whole alphabet
^         e# Symmetric set difference of the alphabet with the vowels, yields the consonants only
\         e# Swap top two elements
1$1$1$    e# Copy the second-from-the-top string to the top three times
          e# This results in the array being consonants-vowels-consonants-vowels-consonants
N         e# Add a newline character to the end of the list
]         e# End an array. Puts everything done so far in an array
          e# since there was no explicit start of the array.
:m*       e# Reduce the array using Cartesian products
```

Comment: `'{,97>` to get the alphabet. And then `"aeiouy"_'{,97>^` to save another byte on `1$`.

Comment: you don't need the very first character. It is assumed if it gets to start of the stack.

Comment: @kaine Interesting, didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: $"aeiouy"_'{,97>^]3*(;:m*N*$  ignore the $ signs. Idk how to put code in comments.

Comment: @kaine Use backticks, like "`".

Answer (score 3):

### Scala, <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```
val a="aeiouy"
val b='a'to'z'diff a
for(c<-b;d<-a;e<-b;f<-a;g<-b)println(""+c+d+e+f+g)
```

Comment: You can replace `f"$c$d$e$f$g"` with `""+c+d+e+f+g` to save a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## Stacked, noncompeting, 51 bytes

```
(consonants:@c vowels:@v c v c)multicartprod$outmap
```

Pretty simple. [Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>111</s> 98 bytes

Added `y` as a vowel, and golfed off 13 bytes, thanks to @Patrick B.

```
l=letters
v=c(1,5,9,15,21,25)
apply(expand.grid(C<-l[-v],V<-l[v],C,V,C)[,5:1],1,cat,fill=T,sep="")
```

We use `expand.grid` to generate all possible combinations of `V` and `C` in a matrix, which we define from the preset variable `letters` (the alphabet). We reverse the combinations (as the default is for the first variable to rotate the fastest) to ensure alphabetical order. Then we iterate through each row of the matrix, printing each letter to stdout. We use the `fill` argument to `cat` to ensure that each word begins on a new line.

Comment: Nice! You can chop this down further to 98 characters (adding 'y' as a vowel, or 95 if not) by using some options in cat and by renaming "letters": l=letters;v=c(1,5,9,15,21,25);apply(expand.grid(C<-l[-v],V<-‌​l[v],C,V,C)[,5:1],1,‌​cat,fill=T,sep="")

Comment: @PatrickB. Thanks! I've incorporated your suggestions.

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8c2J7WkJLWomKvM1sDKVMtUO1nD0ErXUMdAk6u8KLMkVaNEI7WiIDEvRS@9KDNFw9lGNydatyxWJwzEANLOOmE6zprRplaGsZo6hjqmOjpKSpr//wMA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>143</s> 132 bytes

```
q=letters;v=c(1,5,9,15,21,25);x=list(q[-v],q[v],q[-v],q[v],q[-v]);Reduce(paste0,mapply(function(a,b)rep(a,e=b/20),x,cumprod(sapply(x,length))))
```

```
q=letters;v=c(1,5,9,15,21,25);x=list(a<-q[-v],b<-q[v],a,b,a);Reduce(paste0,mapply(function(a,b)rep(a,e=b/20),x,cumprod(lengths(x))))
```

This is my first go at code golf so I'd welcome any suggestions to chop it down further. So far it's all pretty standard R; the only possibly tricky thing here is that paste0 recycles its arguments to the length of the longest one.

Edit: used assignment trick from rturnbull, replaced `sapply(x,length)` with `lengths`.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This looks quite good (I have only programmed a bit in R myself) I would just recommend not including old code in your answer.  The edit history is always available so anyone that wishes to can always view it.  This is more of a personal stylistic thing so feel free to ignore my opinion.

Comment: You can brute-force it with function assignments for [114 bytes](https://tio.run/##PcpBCgIxDEbhu8wqgX9hB7qQkpOoi2HMgCCmbWKvX90oPPg2r8/Z5KkR2r0MaZedEjLOSBlrwpr5VqrUzUNPxcTe37G4uMb9cRzUMLjsW5BbDzJyGA38dFT@x3CtslxfC8/5AQ)!

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>63</s> <s>59</s> 54 bytes

```perl
$a="aeiouy";$b="[^$a][$a]"x2;for("a"x5.."z"x5){say if/$b[^$a]/}
```

```perl
$a="aeiouy";$b="[^$a][$a]"x2;/$b[^$a]/&&say for"a"x5.."z"x5
```

```perl
$a=aeiouy;$b="[^$a][$a]"x2;/$b[^$a]/&&say for a.."z"x5
```

Trying Perl golf for a change.
EDIT: [Looks like](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106574/14880) I've still got much to learn... :)

Comment: Nice one (even if Primo's answer is shorter). You can write the end as `/$b[^$a]/&&say for"a"x5.."z"x5` to save a few bytes. Edit: and you can drop the `$b` and do `$a="aeiouy";/([^$a][$a]){2}[^$a]/&&say for"a"x5.."z"x5`.

Comment: Also, you don't need the quotes around `aeiouy`. Also, since your regex checks for 5 characters, you can do `a.."z"x5`.

Comment: @Dada: Thanks. As someone who uses Perl for normal programming but until now not for golfing, I didn't even think to exploit non-strict mode. That's why I chose `$a` and `$b` as variable names, because those don't need to be declared even in strict mode... :) I also use Perl 6 a lot these days, which doesn't even *have* a non-strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

### C 361 bytes

```
f(){i,j,k,l,m;v[6]={97,101,105,111,117,121};c[25];s=26;for(i=0;i<26;i++)c[i]=97+i;for(i=0;i<26;i++){for(j=0;j<6;j++)if(c[i]==v[j])c[i]+=1;}for(i=0;i<s;i++)for(j=i+1;j<s;){ if(c[i]==c[j]){for(k=j;k<s-1;++k)c[k]=c[k+1];--s;}else ++j;}for(i=0;i<s;i++)for(j=0;j<6;j++)for(k=0;k<s;k++)for(l=0;l<6;l++)for(m=0;m<s;m++)printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n",c[i],v[j],c[k],v[l],c[m]);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void f()
{   
int i,j, k,l,m;
int s=26;
int v[6]={97,101,105,111,117,121};
int c[s];

for(i=0;i<s;i++)
 c[i]=97+i;
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
{     
  for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    if(c[i]==v[j])
      c[i]+=1;
     }
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
 for(j=i+1;j<s;)
 { if(c[i]==c[j])
  {
    for(k=j;k<s-1;++k)
      c[k]=c[k+1];
      --s;  
  }else
   ++j;  
  }
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
  for(j=0;j<6;j++)
       for(k=0;k<s;k++)
        for(l=0;l<6;l++)
         for(m=0;m<s;m++)       
      printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n",c[i],v[j],c[k],v[l],c[m]);
}
```

There must be some way to shorten this definitely.

### Explanation

- Stored the integer values of a,e,i,o,u,y in a numerical array,
- Stored all alphabets in array, if it was a vowel, replaced it with a consonant, so there were duplicate consonant values in the array,
- Removed duplicate consonant values,
- Printed all combinations c-v-c-v-c.

Comment: If you could put an ungolfed version that would help immensely.

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 101 bytes

```
(print(apply str(for[V["aeiouy"]C["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"]a C b V c C d V e C](str a b c d e "\n")))))
```

Not that exciting...

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>65</s> 61 bytes

Completely different approach:

```
(b=[*?a..?z]-a="aeiouy".chars).product(a,b,a,b){|x|puts x*""}
```

New things I learned today: the **Array#product** function

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
s.n*F[K-GJ"aeiouy"JKJKb
```

In pseudocode:

```python
'                       ' G, b = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "\n"
'         J"aeiouy"     ' J = "aeiouy"
'      K-GJ             ' K = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
's.n                    ' "".join( flatten(
'   *F                  '   reduce(cartesian_product,
'     [K           JKJKb'     [K,J,K,J,K,b]
'                       ' # b makes it so that every word ends with \n so that
'                       ' # flattening and concatenating automatically deals with
'                       ' # newlines
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.n%2aF%5BK-GJ%22aeiouy%22JKJKb&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>244</s> <s>242</s> <s>234</s> 219 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){string v="aeiouy",c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";int i=0,j,k,l,m;for(;i<20;i++)for(j=0;j<6;j++)for(k=0;k<20;k++)for(l=0;l<6;l++)for(m=0;m<20;)System.Console.Write("\n"+c[i]+v[j]+c[k]+v[l]+c[m++]);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string v = "aeiouy", c = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";
        int i=0, j, k, l, m;
        for (; i < 20; i++)
            for (j=0; j < 6; j++)
                for (k=0; k < 20; k++)
                    for (l=0; l < 6; l++)
                        for (m=0; m < 20; )
                            System.Console.Write("\n"+c[i]+v[j]+c[k]+v[l]+c[m++]);
    }
}
```

I doubt I can trim it any further.
Done on C# 5, so no {c[i]}

Comment: @dim damn, you are right. Let me rewrite this...

Comment: Are you sure this can't be shortened with Linq?

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 185 bytes

```
@set c=b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x z
@for %%i in (%c%)do @for %%j in (a e i o u y)do @for %%k in (%c%)do @for %%l in (a e i o u y)do @for %%m in (%c%)do @echo %%i%%j%%k%%l%%m
```

Batch is so verbose that it costs 4 bytes to put the vowels into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL, 276

This answer assumes a query's result set is valid output.

```
WITH c AS(SELECT*FROM(VALUES('b'),('c'),('d'),('f'),('g'),('h'),('j'),('k'),('l'),('m'),('n'),('p'),('q'),('r'),('s'),('t'),('v'),('w'),('x'),('z'))c(_)),v AS(SELECT*FROM(VALUES('a'),('e'),('i'),('o'),('u'),('y'))v(_))SELECT c._+v._+b._+a._+d._ FROM c,v,c b,v a,c d ORDER BY 1
```

It works in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I'm not sure currently where you'd be able to run it online given the number of rows returned, though.

One CTE definition holds the consonants from a derived table.  The other holds the vowels from another derived table.  Take the Cartesian product of three consonant CTEs and two vowel CTEs, and you can get an alphabetized list of the appropriately concatenated values.

Comment: Nice, just what I was thinking. If you restrict it to SQL 2016 or higher, you can save ~70 bytes by using [STRING_SPLIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `VALUES`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ØỴ,Øỵṁ5ŒpY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjIe7t@iAyK0PdzaaHp1UEPn/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 93 bytes

```
c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
t=[[a,b]|a<-"aeiuoy",b<-c]
main=putStr$unlines[b:y++z|b<-c,y<-t,z<-t]
```

I have tried to slim the hardcoded lists of consonants and vowels down, but haven't been able to find something that saves bytes. This will output all possible five letter words in the order as stated in the post to stdout, being generated via list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 347 bytes -.-

```
public class N{public static void main(String[]a){String c="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";String v="aeiouy";int[]i=new int[5],e=new int[5];e[0]=e[2]=e[4]=20;e[1]=e[3]=6;m:while(true){System.out.println(c.charAt(i[0])+v.charAt(i[1])+c.charAt(i[2])+v.charAt(i[3])+c.charAt(i[4]));int p=4;while(true){++i[p];if(i[p]<e[p])break;i[p]=0;if(p==0)break m;--p;}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Informix-SQL, 254 bytes

an SQL version  (IBM Informix dialect)

```
select x from table(list{'a','e','i','o','u','y'})(x)
into temp v;
select x from table(list{'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k',
'l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z'})(x)
into temp c;
select k.x||j.x||i.x||v.x||c.x
from c,v,c i,v j,c k
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>52</s></sup> <sup><s>37</s></sup> <sup><s>34</s></sup> 33 bytes

```
echo>,{5$'aeiouy'(-.~;[)u:97+i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I99Op9pURT0xNTO/tFJdQ1evzjpas9TK0lw7U8/I7P9/AA)

*-1 thanks to Adam's suggestion of `u:97+i.26` to replace `26{.97|.a.`*

- `u:97+i.26` extract letters a..z from ascii alphabet `a.`
- `'aeiouy'(-.~;[)` subtract the vowels from a..z, and link `;` that (the consonants) to the vowels, creating a boxed list `consonants ; vowels`.
- `5$` extent that boxed list cyclically to 5 elements, yielding `consonants ; vowels ; consonants ; vowels ; consonants`.
- `{` create the cross product
- `,` flatten
- `>` open the boxes to create regular strings
- `echo` print the results

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) v2, 11 bytes

```
Ḍ;Ẉj,Ḍ∋ᵐcẉ⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GOHuuHuzqydICMRx3dD7dOSH64q/NR19L//wE)

Pretty much the same as Fatalize's Brachylog v1 answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Shell, <s>72</s> 64

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hOl1Pr6q2OlFPL60Wk11TUqSQpFulkJqZX1qZlJySlp6RpZtXoFtSVl5R9f8/AA) (Thanks [@Grimy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6484/grimy))

`echo {g..z}{a..f}{g..z}{a..f}{g..z}|tr b-z eiouybcdfghj-np-tvwxz`

---

If it must be delimited by newlines (beware of the spaces) 69 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hOl1Pr6q2OlFPL60Wk11TUqQQo5CkW6UQE5OXmplfWpmUnJKWnpGlm1egW1JWXlH1/z8A):

`echo {g..z}{a..f}{g..z}{a..f}{g..z}|tr \ b-z \\neiouybcdfghj-np-tvwxz`

---

Original shell, 72 bytes (bash, ksh, zsh, a simple sh may not expand `{..}`) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hOlFPr6S22lBPz6wWk11TUqSQqFtiqGumkJSckpaekZWdk5tXUFhUXFJWXlGVmJqZX1r5/z8A)

`echo {a..t}{1..6}{a..t}{1..6}{a..t}|tr a-t1-6 bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzaeiouy`

Less than half a second. Considering that a C equivalent runs in 0.228sec and a perl equivalent takes 2.1 seconds, this is **Not** slow (times reported as TiO measured them).

Comment: [64](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@hOl1Pr6q2OlFPL60Wk11TUqSQpFulkJqZX1qZlJySlp6RpZtXoFtSVl5R9f8/AA): `echo {g..z}{a..f}{g..z}{a..f}{g..z}|tr b-z eiouybcdfghj-np-tvwxz`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 58 bytes

```sh
v=(a e i o u y)
c=(${${:-{b..z}}:|v})
echo $^c$^v$^c$^v$^c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/zFYjUSFVIVMhX6FUoVKTK9lWQ6VapdpKtzpJT6@qttaqpqxWkys1OSNfQSUuWSWuDE7@/w8A)

`${   :|foo}` is set difference, and `${^foo}` enables brace expansion over the contents of the array `foo`.

---

If newline-delimited is required, **64 bytes**:

```sh
v=(a e i o u y)
c=(${${:-{b..z}}:|v})
<<<${(F):-$^c$^v$^c$^v$^c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/zFYjUSFVIVMhX6FUoVKTK9lWQ6VapdpKtzpJT6@qttaqpqxWk8vGxkalWsNN00pXJS5ZJa4MTtb@/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
k¹k∪"5ẎΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJrwrlr4oiqXCI14bqOzqAiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

```
    "    # Pair
k¹       # Consonants
  k∪     # and vowels
     5Ẏ  # Extend to length 5
       Π # Take the cartesian product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup>40</sup> 35 bytes

```
+x@'!#'x:1_5^[`c$97+!26;]\"aeiouy"
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9KucFBXVFavsDKMN42LTkhWsTTXVjQys46NUUpMzcwvrVRS4OJSTuMyVdA1VY6xSgMATYsMsg==)

-5 : clever shuffling from @ngn.  Constant alphabet, alternating set differences.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-P`, 54 bytes

```bash
v=(a e i o u y)
c=({a..z})
c=(${c:|v})
echo $c$v$c$v$c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjWbSSboBS7IKlpSVpuhY3zcpsNRIVUhUyFfIVShUqNbmSbTWqE_X0qmrBTJXqZKuaMiA7NTkjX0ElWaUMgiG6oYYsgNIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

```perl
y/aeiouy/1/r=~/\D1\D1\D/&&say for a..1x5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79SPzE1M7@0Ut9Qv8i2Tj/GxRCM9NXUihMrFdLyixQS9fQMK4Aq/@UXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>123</s> <s>120</s> 117 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```c
char w[6];f(n,m,c,p){for(n=457653;c=p=n<1<<24;p&&puts(w))for(m=n++;m;m/=26)p*=!index("aeiouy",w[5-c]=m%26+97)^++c%2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrRCoIwFADQ5/wKE5TdNomWTmLeLxEDuWntYXOYYiF@@6LzfCh/EoVAr26K10a1emBOWEHCwzaME3NYlJUqr5rQo6svdS0L7bPML/ObrQD/Y9Fxrq22Z5QK/AmPxj36D0u63ozLNxFrU@bUok2l4rcK7pxTKvUejJtj2xnHINqiw8BAR3v4AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>25</s> 16 bytes

```
╩æ╩¼`┼]m▒ε*mÅ─yn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1JWHlwGJQ3sSHk3ZE5v7aNqkc1u1cg@3PprSUJn3//9/AA)

<s>Definitely not optimal, but this challenge got me to actually implement some features of MathGolf that have been in TODO since forever, mainly string subtraction and vowels/consonants. Once it's up on TIO I'll update this answer.</s> MathGolf has been updated, and I'll add this as a disclaimer that some features used in this answer are newer than the challenge itself.

To fetch consonants and vowels from the dictionary, I filtered out words in the dictionary files which were duplicates, and found that I had 3 duplicates within the top 256 words of the dictionary. I decided that that 2 of these slots should be replaced by the string of consonants and the string of vowels. I was unsure of where "y" should be placed, but decided to place it among the vowels.

The one thing that is not in place is cartesian product for strings. Since I have not defined the output format yet, this feature did not make it into the latest version of MathGolf.

### Explanation

```
╩æ                 fetch dictionary word 145 ("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz")
  ╩¼               fetch dictionary word 172 ("aeiouy")
    `              duplicate the top two items
     ┼             duplicate second item from top and push to top
      ]            end array / wrap stack in array
                   stack is now ["<cons>", "<vow>", "<cons>", "<vow>", "<cons>"]
       m▒          map each element to a list of chars
         ε*        reduce list by multiplication (cartesian product)
           mÅ      explicit map using next 2 operators
             ─     flatten array
              y    join array without separator to string or number
               n   join array with newlines to a string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 224 bytes

```
LIST V=(a),e,i,o,u,y
LIST C=(b),c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,z
~temp D=C
~temp E=V
~temp F=C
~temp G=V
~temp H=C
-(L){D}{E}{F}{G}{H}
~H++
{H:->L}
~H=C
~G++
{G:->L}
~G=V
~F++
{F:->L}
~F=C
~E++
{E:->L}
~E=V
~D++
{D:->L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc3LDoIwFATQfb@CJYThB0zqhr5M2GnY@0BFBFHx2ZRfr7Zp2M09ycytu8baYrFcRSWN1wkq1LjggQ/xmNN4k2CLHfY44IgTGpzRokOPK264Y8ATL7zxJeNQtX3EaB4Sp2VIYjI5mfpbFheJZkZzo4XR0mhlyKjSlGg1y@aFO1xTOpFB/IJwIoL4de6EB/GfmRPmxdof)

Answer (score 0):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/index.html), 57 bytes

```
v=anyOf"aeiouy"
c=anyOf"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
[c,v,c,v,c]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m706ubSoqDK-IDE7uXjBgqWlJWm6FjftymwT8yr905QSUzPzSyuVuJKh_KTklLT0jKzsnNy8gsKi4pKy8ooqJa7cxMw82-hknTIdMI6FmAI1DGYoAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 80 bytes

```javascript
f=(i=5,s)=>i?[...i%2?'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz':'aeiouy'].flatMap(e=>f(i-1,[s]+e)):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFREoIgEADQ0zTsTspMzfRjg56gEzh@EIKtEZCLWl2e3pv1ptkslHId4mhLcQpIXSpG1VLXSynpcO7E3YxuesxP/wrpvXDe9s9PNEJbiutXDNJ5nW86gVWtA6pPVc/D0SI2XEwMHL2VPk7gAPFa/g)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

```javascript
f=(i=5,s='',j=35,c=j.toString(36))=>+c?'':i?f(i,s,j-1)+(i%2^/[aeiouy]/.test(c)?f(i-1,s+c):''):s+' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEADAr3iR3SVpSi31kBL7CI@iEGJaNpRGulHw9RHnPMl/vISdX6XZ8jPWOjtkN2hxADq5ftDBJVPytey8LdifidxFhQnA8jQja9Gp6UghH0@P9uYj5/f33poSpWCgf2k6LSqQBSArCg5QQ94kr9GsecEZicb6Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, 82 bytes

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboWN4Oik5JT0tIzsrJzcvMKCouKS8rKK6pioxNTM_NLK2PJkYWYDLVgAZQGAA)

Unfortunately, there's no clever way to do this in Regenerate--just gotta list all the options.